# Display user info from Firebase

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase

I want to read and display user info from Firebase. 
Here is how far I've got:

```
     class UserInfoViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        var ref: DatabaseReference!
       private var gotName = [""]


        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return gotName.count
        }

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserInfoCell") as! UserInfoTableViewCell



            cell.nameLabel.text = gotName[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }  



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        ref?.child("users").child(user).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
                let name = userDict["Name"] as? String else {
                    return
            }

            //Declare variables for use
            self.gotName = [name]

        })

    }
}
```

**Firebase structure:**

```
-users    
   -----5DzurQyzyIbXfFCbAxc4ynwizYJ2    
   ---------John Doe
```

I want the current user to be displayed in the nameLabel

Comment: can you show us your firebase structure?

Comment: Sorry, I managed to edit out most of code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the code correctly.
but you must reload your table view after downloading the data from firebase.
Just write following code after `self.gotName = [name]` in your firebase observer.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope this helps